# Custom protcol interceptor to Apache HttpClient to process exceptions

Tags: apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

How can I write a protocol interceptor for ApacheHttpClient that can intercept when there is a Connection or Socket timeout, so I can handle the exception in my interceptor method?

I already have a HttpResponseInterceptor, but that gets called only when we have a successful response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocol interceptors can act on a valid HTTP message only. In case of an I/O error they are useless. You should be using `HttpRequestRetryHandler` instead